# Como eliminar caracteres que no seas letras ni números de un String?

Tags: java

Ejemplo

Ingreso **`‘HDXU`**   Salida :   **`HDXU`**

Ingreso **`'HD XU''`**   Salida :   **`HDXU`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con Un Patrón, usando el método [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) , el Regex a usar será `[^\\dA-Za-z]`

- `^`  Negación
- `\\d` Dígitos [0-9]
- `A-Za-z` Letras mayúsculas como minúsculas

Cualquier carácter de la cadena que **NO** coincida con el patrón , es decir que no sea dígito ni una letra,  se reemplazamos con un `""`

**Ejemplo**

```
String valor = "‘HDXU-----?s-";
System.out.println(valor.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z]", ""));
/* Otro Regex*/
System.out.println(valor.replaceAll("[\\W]|_", "")); 
/* Otro Regex*/
System.out.println(valor.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
```

**Salida**

```
HDXUs
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. me funciono

Comment: Tu segunda regex esta mal. \\W ya es la negación de `word`, así eliminas todas caracteres `word`.

Comment: @StefanNolde gracias , se me había pasado la negación.